# SparseBooleanArray.equals() not working as expected

Tags: java, android, sparse-matrix

In the following code I would expect `equals()` to return `true`, but it does not. What am I missing here?

```
    SparseBooleanArray array_0 = new SparseBooleanArray();
    array_0.put(0, true);
    array_0.put(2, true);

    SparseBooleanArray array_1 = new SparseBooleanArray();
    array_1.put(0, true);
    array_1.put(2, true);

    boolean isEqual = array_0.equals(array_1); // is false instead of true
```

Looking at both array in the debugger, they seem the same to me (they have a different `shadow$_monitor_` value, but I have no idea what that is supposed to be). The `toString()` method returns the same string for both as well.

I am trying to write a unit test for a function that converts an `EnumSet` to a `SparseBooleanArray`, but I can't create the same array manually to compare it with the function's return value.

---

**Edit**

I should also mention that `hasCode()` returns different values as well, which should not, based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html#hashCode()).

Comment: That is very odd. I can reproduce your findings, but the source code looks like they should match...

Comment: on which version of android are you testing it ?

Comment: @Blackbelt On Android 6.0 API 23 - x86_64 emulator

Comment: Looking at the sources of `v23` and `equals` is not overriden, so it returns false.

Comment: have a look [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/3b409d01b9511e196ca5ad746c44fd93925ab1b8%5E%21/core/java/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.java) and/or [here](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-23/blob/master/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.java)

Comment: @Blackbelt I guess it is deliberately not included. Looking at the documentation, it does say that the array has `equales(Object o) `method and not the `equals(SparseBooleanArray o)`. Which would indicate that the proper `equals()` method is not implemented. I guess I will compare `toString()` results for now.

Comment: I wouldn't say deliberately. You could still subclass `SparseBooleanArray` and add equals and hashCode. I would say better than comparing toString. My two cents

Comment: @Blackbelt Sincle all the member variables are private, I am not sure what I could do in `equals()` of the subclass. For now I only compare arrays in a unit test, so I can live with `toString()` :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code both the `equals` and `hashCode` methods are not implemented for `SparseBooleanArray`, `SparseIntArray`, `SparseLongArray` and `SparseArray`. I would say this is a critical missing feature and should be reported to Google.

Anyway, I use for quite some time these utility methods to solve this problem:

```
public static boolean equals(SparseArray arrayOne, SparseArray arrayTwo){
    if(arrayOne == arrayTwo){
        return true;
    } else if(arrayOne.size() != arrayTwo.size()){
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayOne.size(); i++){
        if(arrayOne.keyAt(i) != arrayTwo.keyAt(i)){
            return false;
        }
        final Object valueOne = arrayOne.valueAt(i);
        final Object valueTwo = arrayTwo.valueAt(i);
        if(valueOne != null && !valueOne.equals(valueTwo)){
            return false;
        } else if(valueTwo != null && !valueTwo.equals(valueOne)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean equals(SparseBooleanArray arrayOne, SparseBooleanArray arrayTwo){
    if(arrayOne == arrayTwo){
        return true;
    } else if(arrayOne.size() != arrayTwo.size()){
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayOne.size(); i++){
        if(arrayOne.keyAt(i) != arrayTwo.keyAt(i)){
            return false;
        } else if(arrayOne.valueAt(i) != arrayTwo.valueAt(i)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean equals(SparseIntArray arrayOne, SparseIntArray arrayTwo){
    if(arrayOne == arrayTwo){
        return true;
    } else if(arrayOne.size() != arrayTwo.size()){
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayOne.size(); i++){
        if(arrayOne.keyAt(i) != arrayTwo.keyAt(i)){
            return false;
        } else if(arrayOne.valueAt(i) != arrayTwo.valueAt(i)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public static boolean equals(SparseLongArray arrayOne, SparseLongArray arrayTwo){
    if(arrayOne == arrayTwo){
        return true;
    } else if(arrayOne.size() != arrayTwo.size()){
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayOne.size(); i++){
        if(arrayOne.keyAt(i) != arrayTwo.keyAt(i)){
            return false;
        } else if(arrayOne.valueAt(i) != arrayTwo.valueAt(i)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It is however also possible (as mentioned in the comments), and possibly better,  to subclass the `SparseArray` class and override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

> **Disclaimer:** I did not test the `hashCode` or `equals` implementation of the code provided below, please write some tests yourself to make sure it works correctly. #DontTrustTheInternet

```
public class SparseBooleanArray extends android.util.SparseBooleanArray {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(!(o instanceof SparseBooleanArray)){
            return false;
        } else if(this == o){
            return true;
        }
        final SparseBooleanArray other = (SparseBooleanArray) o;
        if(size() != other.size()){
            return false;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++){
            if(keyAt(i) != other.keyAt(i)){
                return false;
            } else if(valueAt(i) != other.valueAt(i)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++){
            result = 31 * result + keyAt(i);
            result = 31 * result + (valueAt(i)?1:0);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```